# FIND_IN_SET throws "not-recognized built-in function name" error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, odbc

Below is my query for using FIND_IN_SET to check if the value "1" is in the column "DefinedGroup" which will have comma-separated values

```
$q=$this->usermanagement->query("
SELECT momentsdetail.id,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       filepath,
       appcreateddate,
       senderid
FROM   momentsdetail
       INNER JOIN users
               ON users.id = senderid
       INNER JOIN moments
               ON moments.id = momentsdetail.momentsid
WHERE  momentsdetail.remarks IS NULL
       AND Find_in_set('1', definedgroup)
ORDER  BY appcreateddate DESC")
```

**Error:**

> A database error occurred
>
> Error Number:42000/195
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'FIND_IN_SET'
>   is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: provide your error in text format.

Comment: this is the error:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'FIND_IN_SET' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Well, as the error says: SQL Server does not know anything about `'FIND_IN_SET`. Seems to be MySql specific. See here for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725675/sql-server-2014-equivalent-to-mysqls-find-in-set